# How to uploading images in a long form using Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, file-upload

I have a long form consisting of various image uploads. I am using a MEAN stack and using 3 API for this form. One API for profile pic upload, one API for documents upload, last API for entering information about documents.

The last part i.e. entering info works for me but not the images upload part, be it profile pic or documents uploading. I am not sure about how to include all api in one single controller and make it work.

profile pic upload part

```
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="myFileField" class="control-label">Profile Picture</label>
      <input type="file" demo-file-model="myFile" name="file"  class="form-control" id ="myFileField"/>
  </div>
```

Documents Upload part

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.name.$dirty && form.name.$error.required }">
    <label for="name" class="control-label" >Driving License</label>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" ng-model="drivingLicence.drivingLicenceNo" placeholder="Enter name as per SSLC marksheet" required>
    </div>
</div>
```

Documents information part

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <label for="myFileField" class="control-label">Driving License Number</label>
     <input type="file" demo-file-model="myFile" name="file"  class="form-control" id ="myFileField"/>
 </div>
```

Controller Part

```
(function() {
'use strict';
var myApp = angular.module('app');

/*
 A directive to enable two way binding of file field
 */
myApp.directive('demoFileModel', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A', //the directive can be used as an attribute only

        /*
         link is a function that defines functionality of directive
         scope: scope associated with the element
         element: element on which this directive used
         attrs: key value pair of element attributes
         */
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.demoFileModel),
                modelSetter = model.assign; //define a setter for demoFileModel

            //Bind change event on the element
            element.bind('change', function () {
                //Call apply on scope, it checks for value changes and reflect them on UI
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    //set the model value
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
})();



 (function () 
 {
  'use strict';
   var myApp = angular.module('app');
   myApp.controller('Home.IndexController', function ($scope,    fileUploadService) 
 {
    $scope.otherMarksCards = [];
    $scope.otherCertificates = [];
    $scope.uploadFile = function ()
    {
        var file = $scope.myFile;


  $http.put('https://student.herokuapp.com/user/documentsRelatedInfo', 
        {

    "drivingLicence": {
                              "drivingLicenceNo": $scope.drivingLicence.drivingLicenceNo,
                              "url": ""
                       },
  }).success(function(response) 
                                    {
                                      console.log(response);
                                    })

                             promise = fileUploadService.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl); 
                             promise.then(function (response) 
                                         {
                                             $scope.serverResponse = response;
                                         }, function () {
                                            $scope.serverResponse = 'An error has occurred';
                                                        }
                                          )
    };
});

})();


 (function () 
  {
            'use strict';
            var myApp = angular.module('app');
            myApp.service('fileUploadService', function ($http, $q) 
            {

                this.uploadFileToUrl = function (file, uploadUrl) 
                {
                    //FormData, object of key/value pair for form fields and values
                    var fileFormData = new FormData();
                    fileFormData.append('file', file);

                    var deffered = $q.defer();
                    $http.put("https://student.herokuapp.com/user/addDocument", fileFormData, 
                    {
                        transformRequest: angular.identity,
                        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}

                    }).success(function (response) 
                        {
                           deffered.resolve(response);

                        }).error(function (response)
                             {
                                deffered.reject(response);
                             })

                            return deffered.promise;
                }

            });

 })();
```

Comment: use ng-file-upload : https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Comment: Why can't it be done without using ng-file-upload?

Comment: its a ready to use best file upload angular-module that u can use, and yes u can write your own code if you want to learn.